# What happened with good old Histogram?

Tags: histograms

For the sake of demonstration in a class I wanted to use the line:

```
Histogram[Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100000]], {1}, "Probability"]
```

to get a probability-like distribution of the random walk process. This worked for me on Mma7, 8, and 9 returning a reasonable probability-like histogram. As soon as I do it now (Mma 10.0.2, Win7) I get for several times the desired histogram. However, after several (about 10) trials I suddenly see the word "Histogram" appearing in red color, and the whole thing stops working, with a message that Histogram is obsolete.
So, (i) what happened? and (ii) Could I repair it?

Comment: Hmmm, no problems on a MacBook with Mathematica 10.0.2, code seems to work as it should...

Comment: Same on Mathematica 10.0.0 Windows 8, no errors.  Can you reproduce it just by running only that input line a couple of times in a fresh kernel?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce it with Mma 10.0.2 and Win7.

Comment: I'm curious whether you can still reproduce this Alexei?  I can get an error out of your command (MMA 10.2, Linux) but not after 10 trials, after a hundred or more, and my error is different as well.  The error message is [here](http://i.imgur.com/ArUNDaE.png)

Comment: @Jason B  I tried with Mma10.2 several possibilities, such as plain line given above, `Table[...,{200}]` and `Do[...,{i,200}]`, where inside the operators there always was  the above Histogram statement. No problem now. At least I did not notice with 200 repetitions.

Answer (score 1):

For Mathematica 10.2.0.0 there is no problem:

[image]